# Spyder closes when u close cmd showing "activate code page 1252"

Tags: cmd, anaconda, spyder

Whenever u run spyder from anaconda navigator cmd windows open with message " activate code page 1252 "
if u close cmd then then spyder also closes

It's a problem with Anaconda Navigator. The following solution worked for some people but not me

In Anaconda Navigator > File Menu > Preferences > Configure Conda > Reset to defaults > Save and Restart

Anaconda Navigator > File Menu > Preferences > Configure Navigator > Reset to defaults > Save and Restart

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please use our Windows installer to solve this problem. You can find it [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases).

Comment: Is there a way to use Windows installer to install Spyder into Anaconda environment? @CarlosCordoba

Comment: No, sorry. Instead, you need to connect our Windows installer to Anaconda, as described [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer).

Comment: thanks @CarlosCordoba, but this didn't really work.
when I try to use conda to install spyder-kernels it stucks at solving environment (just like when I try updating spyder directly in anaconda)
I tried to use pip, it worked but spyder still didn't recognize it

Comment: Ok, sorry to hear that. Anaconda's support is not the best these days. That's why we're adding environment and package installation facilities to our installers, which should arrive by the end of the year.

Comment: Any news on this? Active code page error is frustrating right now and at still stucs at solving environment. I'm a tidy person. Can't code with an open cmd prompt.

Comment: @colt.exe is the error in the OP title spelled correctly? I'm getting "Active code page:1252"

Comment: @gciriani Uhm for me its 1254. But I developed a habit to ignore it.

Comment: @colt.exe, I was rather questioning the word Activate vs Active.

Comment: @gciriani It is "Active code page: 1254"